# Why does my component not see a method within a service

Tags: angular

I am creating a component that will request data from a service on initialisation.

The service exists within a shared module that is imported into a feature module in which my new component exists.

The problem I have is that when I call the 'getControl' method,  I am getting some errors to the effect of:

Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

When I console.log the service I can see it exists, but the getControl method returns as undefined.

collection.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlsService } from '../../../shared/services/controls.service'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-collection',
  templateUrl: './collection.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./collection.component.css'],
})

export class CollectionComponent implements OnInit {

  control$:Observable<any> 

  id:string = "9FC34C22-CB9A-C985-3EAD-33443295AC6C"

  constructor(public controlService:ControlsService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(">>CollectionComponent:ngOnInit--") 
    this.controlService.getControl(this.id).subscribe(res => {this.control$ = res});
  }

}
```

control.service.ts

```js
import { Injectable }    from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

import {BaseService} from './base.service'


@Injectable()
export class ControlsService {


    apiUrl = './data/controls.json'; 

    public data:any

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    public getData(): Observable<any> 
    {
        console.log(">>BaseService:getData--")

        return this.http.get(this.apiUrl)
                        .map(this.extractData)
                        .catch(this.handleError);
    }   


    public getControl(controlID:any): Observable<any> 
    {
        console.log(">>ControlsService:getControl--")
        if(!this.data)
        {
            this.getData().subscribe(res => {
                                            this.data = res;
                                            this.getControl(controlID)
                                            }
                                    )
        }
        else
        {
            let     returnData:Observable<any> = this.data.filter(control => control.id == controlID)
            return  returnData  
        }

    }   


    public extractData(res: Response) 
    {
        console.log(">>ControlsService:extractData--")
        let body = res.json();
        this.data = body.data.control
        return this.data || { };
    }

    private handleError (error: any) 
    {
       console.log(">>BaseService:handleError--")
       let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message : error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
       console.error(errMsg); // log to console instead
       return Observable.throw(errMsg);
    }
}
```

The console errors also do not reveal in which file the errors exist.
I would appreciate if someone could take a look and tell me where I am going wrong.

Comment: Well, your getControl() method indeed doesn't return anything this.data is falsy.

Comment: your service implementation is -at best- very weird, what are you trying to do ?

Comment: In the service I want to make a call to the server once to retreive an array of data, then once the array is returned to the service I want to return to the component only one item in the array

Comment: I could simply request the array from the server on each sercive call and then filter the array to match the id, but this would make many many calls to the server , which I want to avoid doing